# Equality with powers of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, noetherian

> Let $A$ be an arbitrary (commutative with an identity) ring. Suppose $\alpha$ is an ideal. Is it true that $$\alpha(\alpha\cap\alpha^2\cap\alpha^3\cap…)=\alpha\cap\alpha^2\cap\alpha^3\cap…?$$

I’m really sorry if this is absolutely obvious or absolutely wrong. For example, if $\exists k$ such that $\alpha^k=\alpha^{k+1}=…$ then $\alpha\cap\alpha^2\cap\alpha^3\cap…=\alpha^k$ and the identity I want to prove becomes obvious. I'll be grateful for any help!

> I'd like to add that we may suppose $A$ to be noetherian and $\alpha$ the only maximal ideal.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71699/counter-examples-to-krulls-intersection-theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality holds because $\alpha \cap \alpha^2 \cap \ldots$ is actually the zero ideal by Krull's intersection theorem. You may want to read 2.3, 2.4 and 2.5 of [these notes](http://www.math.ccu.edu.tw/~hjwang/93Icom4.pdf).

Comment: @user26857 Indeed, at the end of OP's post it is stated "we may suppose $A$ to be noetherian".